# How to find closest pair or triplet, consecutive numbers group from a python list

Tags: python-3.x

i have a list of values `[4, 5, 18, 19, 20, 30, 31]` and i am trying to making pair, triplet or 4,5.

```
l = [4, 5, 18, 19, 20, 30, 31]
```

*this list need to convert like p_list*

```
p_list = [(4,5),(18,19,20),(30,31)]
```

Comment: What characteristics of the list values determines whether the next value is part of the tuple?  for example, it looks like the differential between 5 and 18 is cause to start a new tuple, but the differential between 32 and 34 is not.  What is the minimum offset that trigger the start of a new tuple?

Comment: actually these list contains a calender dates, from a hotel reservation and each tuple is available days from calender and the difference between each tuple element is 1 lets say (4,5)  5-4=1 and  (18,19,20)  19-18 =1 , 20-19=1.

Comment: Your list has a pattern that enables grouping by consecutive integers. I don't know if that's the case for you. If so, you achieve the expected result with `[tuple(g) for g in more_itertools.consecutive_groups(l)]`.

Comment: that works man.